# Basic Python+C integration

Tags: python, c

I have the following code which is incredible slow when running in python:

```
items = Item.objects.all()

new_list = []
for line in open(file, 'r').readlines():
    if line in items:
        new_list.append(line)
```

This might take about 1 hour to run. How would I do this for loop in C, something like:

```
items = Item.objects.all() # 1M+ objects

new_list = c_function()
```

Comment: Have you tried using a set?

Comment: This is Django right?

Comment: First, are you sure you need to do it in C? If you write this as a list comprehension or a call to `filter`, a lot of the slow looping-in-Python and calling-`list.append` part is optimized for free; try `new_list = [id for id in list_of_ids if id in items]` or `new_list = list(filter(items.__contains__, list_of_ids))`.

Comment: Also, what type is `items`? If it's a `list` or something else with linear-time searching, then it doesn't really matter what language it's in, it's going to be way too slow, because you've got an O(NM) algorithm instead of an O(N) algorithm. Change it to a `set` (or possibly some kind of sorted, logarithmic collection) instead of a `list`.

Comment: Also, are you using any libraries that aren't compatible with PyPy? If not, have you tried just running in PyPy? (I suspect that using the right data structure will already get you the orders-of-magnitude speedup you want, switching to a comprehension of `filter` call will squeeze out another 10-50%, and PyPy's JIT will get you another 10-50% at best in this case… but you never know, and you might as well try.)

Comment: I'm reading a file for this so I can't really get out of the for loop. Is there another way to do the above?

Comment: @David542: What makes you think you can't get out of the for loop? You can use a list of strings in a comprehension, `filter` call, `set.intersection` call, etc. just as easily as anything else. And, even better, you can use the file there in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can explain how to rewrite this in C, but first let me explain why you probably don't want to.

---

Your biggest problem most likely has nothing to do with Python being slow, but with using a quadratic algorithm instead of a linear one. If `items` is a `list`, or any other kind of unordered sequence, `if id in items` is going to have to do a full literal search through all of `items` for each `id`. That will take forever, no matter what language you do it in. If you use a `set`, or any other kind of hash table (or a logarithmic binary-searchable collection), then `if id in items` will take very little time for each `id`, no matter how big `items` is, and it will be more than fast enough in Python.

Even if you can't change the code that returns `items`, just constructing a `set` out of it right before searching that set will give you a massive speedup in exchange for the tiny performance hit of an extra pass:

```
items = set(items)
```

---

Your second biggest problem also has nothing to do with Python being slow:

```
for line in open(file, 'r').readlines():
```

You're reading the entire file into memory, then splitting it into a giant list in memory, before you can even start working. There is literally no reason to do this except to slow your code down. Files are *already* iterables of lines of text. Just change this to:

```
for line in open(file, 'r'):
```

You should use a `with` statement rather than just calling `open` and leaking the file:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
```

---

If that's still too slow, well, now we've reached something that is Python's fault. Python loops are slow, and calling `list.append` dynamically is also slow, and you're doing that right in the middle of your inner loop.

But you can eliminate both of these problems, from within Python, by using a comprehension, calling `filter`, or, simplest of all (if you don't need to preserve the order of the ids), calling `set.intersect`.

Again, since files are iterables, you can just use the file in any of these:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    new_list = [line for line in f if line in items]

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    new_list = list(filter(items.__contains__, f))

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    new_set = items.intersect(f)
```

Either way, you're moving the slow looping into C and replacing the dynamic call to `list.append` with a direct call to the underlying C function. So, you've effectively rewritten the slowest part of your code in C, while still remaining in Python.

---

If you haven't tried [PyPy](http://pypy.org/), and you aren't using any non-PyPy-compatible libraries, try replacing CPython with PyPy. If you've made the above fixes, there's probably not much more it can do with this code, but I've been surprised before… and its JIT optimizer could definitely radically speed up some surrounding code.

---

If you really want to write this in C, however, you can. I'd strongly consider using [Cython](http://cython.org/) first, which will compile almost any native Python code into a C extension, and which is very easy to hint with static types. But let's see how you'd write this in native C.

```
static PyObject *
mymodule_idfilter(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    const char *pathname = NULL;
    FILE *f = NULL;
    PyObject *items = NULL;
    char line[1024];
    PyObject *line_obj = NULL;
    PyObject *result = NULL;
    int contains;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "so", &pathname, &items))
        goto err;
    f = fopen(pathname, "r");
    if (!f)
        goto err;

    result = PyList_New(0);
    if (!result)
        goto err;

    while (!feof(f) && !ferror(r)) {
        /* NOTE: If your lines can be arbitrary length, this will
           do the wrong thing; presumably the first 1023 bytes of
           the line won't match anything in items, and neither will
           the remainder... if you want to handle that, that's
           simple C programming, nothing to do with Python */
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line)-1, f)) {
            line_obj = PyString_FromString(line);
            if (!line_obj)
                goto_err;
            contains = PySequence_Contains(items, id);
            if (contains == -1)
                goto err;
            if (contains == 1)
                if (!PyList_Append(result, id))
                    goto err;
            Py_DECREF(line_obj);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    Py_DECREF(items);
    return result;
err:
    if (f) fclose(f);
    Py_XDECREF(lineobj);
    Py_XDECREF(items);
    Py_XDECREF(id);
    Py_XDECREF(result);
    return NULL;
}
```

Of course the inner core of the loop is calling `PySequence_Contains(items, id)`, which is effectively doing the same work as `id in items` (including dynamically looking up the `__contains__` method and everything), so that part won't be any faster. The fact that we're using `PyList_Append` instead of `list.append` will speed things up, but not much more than a list comprehension or `filter` would, because they effectively do the same. The fact that we're looping over the file with `fgets` instead of `file.__next__` will speed things up, but since we end up constructing a Python string and looking it up in a set of Python strings we're still doing a lot of the same work; at best I'd expect a 30% speedup here—and at the cost of flexibility—arbitrary-length strings, optional universal newlines, Unicode (if you were using Python 3.x), …

If you actually want to make this significantly faster, you're going to have to replace that `items` with a wrapper around some C-implemented hash table of unboxed C strings; then you can avoid dealing with boxing, unboxing, and refcounting entirely within the inner loop. But that requires major changes outside the code you asked about.

Answer (score 0):

```
items = Item.objects.all()

new_list = []
for line in open(file, 'r').readlines():
    if line in items:
        new_list.append(line)
```

There is some improvement possible here, particularly the 'if line in items':
Convert `items` into a dictionary. Then the 'in' function will hash the
key and find it without having to run over the complete list each time.

To convert items to a dictionary, look at the fromkeys(list) method.

Comment: Why would you use a dictionary instead of a set if you have no values for the keys?